# Wrong language in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, language

My system is showing everything in Russian.  How can I change it back to English or German? I have Windows XP sp3.

Answer (score 2):

[Set up Windows XP for multiple languages (Microsoft.com)](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/setup/winxp/yourlanguage.mspx)

or

[HOW TO:Change language settings in Windows XP (ektron.com)](http://dev.ektron.com/kb_article.aspx?id=5982)